# Coordenadas en el tablero con llenado de tiros en Java (matrices)

Tags: java, array, arraylist, matrices, booleano

hoy tuve un examen de programación, e hicimos el siguiente ejercicio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Hice mi código, pero no sale exactamente como yo desearía ver en el ejemplo.
Tengo un problema exactamente a la hora de imprimir las coordendas donde cayeron los códigos y no sé cómo representarlos (lo que está encerrado en rojo es lo que quiero hacer).
Quisiera aclarar que aún soy nuevo en Java, me he estado acostumbrando, aunque quisiera buscar mejores formas de optimizar mis códigos.

Este es mi código:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int row = r.nextInt(2)+4, col = r.nextInt(2)+4;
    int sum = 0;
    int tiradas = 0;
    String posicion = " ";
    int aleatorio = r.nextInt(4)+3;
    int[][] board = new int[row][col];
    int[][] tiros = new int[row][col];

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(500);
    list.add(1000);
    list.add(2000);
    list.add(3000);
    list.add(5000);

    System.out.println("||||||||||||||||TABLERO||||||||||||||||\n");
    for(int x = 0;  x < board.length; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < board[0].length; y++) {
            board[x][y]=list.get(r.nextInt(list.size()));
            String val = String.format("%4s", board[x][y]);
            System.out.print(" ["+val+"] ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    System.out.println("\n Oportunidades: "+aleatorio);

    boolean seguir = true;
    while (seguir) {

        row = r.nextInt(board.length);
        col = r.nextInt(board[0].length);

        if (tiros[row][col] == 0) {
            tiros[row][col] = board[row][col];
            tiradas++;
            sum += tiros[row][col];
        }
        if (tiradas == aleatorio)
        seguir = false;
    }

    System.out.println("\n\n||||||||||||||||TIROS||||||||||||||||\n");
    for (int x = 0; x < board.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < board[0].length; y++) {
            if (tiros[x][y] != 0) {
                String val = String.format("%4s", board[x][y]);
                System.out.print(" [" + val + "] ");

            }else {
                System.out.print(" [    ] ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
    for (int x = 1; x <=aleatorio; x++) {
        posicion = " ["+row+"],["+col+"] ";
        System.out.println("Posición: "+posicion);
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("SUMATORIA: " + sum + "\n");

}
```

Cuando ejecuto el código, imprime todo menos lo de las posiciones donde caen los tiros y su respectivo valor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿cuál es el problema, error o duda exacta, la forma en que se muestra el resultado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede usar un lista para guardar cada acierto

```
List<String> aciertos = new ArrayList<>();
```

Dentro del bucle while

```
while (seguir) {
    row = r.nextInt(board.length);
    col = r.nextInt(board[0].length);
        if (tiros[row][col] == 0) {
            tiros[row][col] = board[row][col];
            tiradas++;
            // lineas agregadas
            String s = "posición: ["+row+"]["+col+"] = "+tiros[row][col];
            aciertos.add(s);
            sum += tiros[row][col];
        }
        if (tiradas == aleatorio)
        seguir = false;
    }
```

Para mostrar los resultados

```
    for(String s : aciertos) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias,ya aparecen las posiciones con las coordenadas y sus respectivos valores.